# Kafka Streams 2.5.0 requires input topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Starting with Kafka Streams 2.5.0 it seems like a topology must include an input topic. In Kafka 2.4.1 (and earlier) that is not the case.

I have an application where the topology is just creating a few global state stores that read in data from topics written to by other applications.

With Kafka 2.5.0 I get this error:

```
13:24:27.161 [<redacted>-7cf1b5c9-4a6e-4bf2-9f77-f7f85f2df3bb-StreamThread-1] ERROR o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [<redacted>-7cf1b5c9-4a6e-4bf2-9f77-f7f85f2df3bb-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following error during processing:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Consumer is not subscribed to any topics or assigned any partitions
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1228)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:853)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:753)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670)
```

If I add a dummy input topic (e.g. via `streamsBuilder.stream(Pattern.compile("hack"));`) the application starts fine.

Is this behavior to be expected or is it an unintentional change in Kafka Streams 2.5.0?

More details: The use case above may seem a bit weird and I would have to agree. The reason for doing it in the first place was a shortcoming of Interactive Queries where for periods of time the application could not answer queries. I see that issue has been fixed in Kafka Streans 2.5.0 via [KIP-535](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-535%3A+Allow+state+stores+to+serve+stale+reads+during+rebalance) which is great. I hope to look into IQ again later.

Comment: This seems to be a regression bug... I guess, it would be fixed via https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9127

Comment: Thank you, Matthias. I hoped it would be a regression that would be fixed in an upcoming version.

Comment: There should be a workaround: Try setting `num.stream.threads = 0` -- please me us know if that works.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works but it has a side effect where the Kafka Streams state no longer transitions to `RUNNING`. I added comments to S Blee-G's answer.

Comment: Interesting finding! Thanks for the information!

Comment: I had the same issue, with Kafka Streams 2.5.0 and still am getting this issue. Is the fix not applied yet? BTW that is awesome way out. num.stream.threads = 0 will not help as it will definitely throw threads count can't be 0

Comment: I have a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/65792786/6621377. I have changed the "kafka-streams" version from2.5.1 to 2.6.0. But i still get the error as "Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table." Can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a regression introduced in 2.5.0 when we switched (back) to using [collection subscription](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7317). A [fix](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/8540) was just merged, so you should upgrade to 2.5.1 or 2.6 when they are released.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue has been fixed in 2.6.0. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any non-global parts of your topology, there's no reason to have any StreamThreads at all. Meaning you can easily work around this by just setting `num.threads` to zero -- arguably, you should be doing this anyways to avoid unnecessary overhead and group coordination. Setting this to zero by default when a global-only topology is detected is the "fix" anyway, so you don't need to wait for that

Comment: While I can confirm that setting `num.stream.threads=0` enables my global-only topology to start, it has an interesting side effect. The Kafka Streams state now just transitions from `CREATED` to `REBALANCING` but never to `RUNNING`. Using the hack in my original question means that the state transitions to `RUNNING`. I find this to be of interest since currently I have health checks for Kubernetes that look at the Kafka Streams state and `RUNNING` so far seemed to be a reasonable state to expect for a healthy Kafka Streams application.

Comment: I have not seen mentioned anywhere (expect now here and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9127) that `num.stream.threads=0` should be used for global-only topologies. Did I miss something? Or maybe it is just because I thought that `num.stream.threads` had to be 1 or larger and instead of increasing it above `1`, you may instead start more instances of your Kafka Streams application.

Comment: Oh right, the global thread doesn't trigger a transition to `RUNNING` :/ This will also be fixed in the PR for KAFKA-9127 and backported to 2.5, but for now your workaround with the dummy pattern sounds best.

Comment: By the way, I didn't mean to imply that you should have known to set the threads to zero, just that it was in your best interest to do so. I don't think anyone thought to document this, or even that it was possible, because we didn't expect people to be running global-only streams apps. Out of curiosity, can you describe your use case?

Comment: Technically you could rework the healthcheck to take `REBALANCING` as "healthy" since a topology without any stream threads will never actually be rebalancing. If you have more than one instance running that might be preferable.

Comment: Thanks, S Blee-G, I will keep my hack around until KAFKA-9127 arrives.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not that happy with our global-only approach but it gets the job done at the moment even though restore times can be annoying. We ended up using it because we, at the time (1,5 years ago), did not believe we could use the Interactive Queries feature due to it sometimes being unable to answer queries. It sounds like [KIP-535](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-535%3A+Allow+state+stores+to+serve+stale+reads+during+rebalance) could make IQ a better solution than a global-only app.

Comment: Yeah, KIP-535 might be exactly what you need. Note that KIP-441 should also greatly help improve the availability of stores in certain scenarios. It's on target for the next release (version2.6): https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-441%3A+Smooth+Scaling+Out+for+Kafka+Streams

Comment: S Blee-G, I have upvoted some of your comments. I have not accepted your current answer as I think the right answer (as you hinted at in comments) will be to upgrade to the next Kafka Streams release (2.5.1 I guess) when that is released. Feel free to add an answer I can accept.

Comment: What qualifies as a Global-Only Topology? Is it only applicable if the source & the sink for Kafka Streams are Global KTables, or is also a Global Only Topology if I have a Kafka topic as source and another topic as sink. Please help!

Comment: Global-only means that you only have Global KTables, and no regular KTables or KStreams

Answer (score 0):

```
private void subscribeConsumer() {
    if (builder.usesPatternSubscription()) {
        // this is old behaviour - is there a config that will revert to this??
        consumer.subscribe(builder.sourceTopicPattern(), rebalanceListener);
    } else {
        consumer.subscribe(builder.sourceTopicCollection(), rebalanceListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or another question?