# Getting store for GlobalKTable crashes after upgrading to kafka-streams:5.5.0-css (Apache Kafka 2.5.0) [RESOLVED]

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot App using GlobalKTable. It worked fine until the update to kafka-streams-5.5.0-css (Confluent Platform version compatible with Apache Kafka 2.5.0 ) from 5.3.2-css (
Apache Kafka 2.3.1).

So this is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class GlobalTableConfiguration {

    public GlobalTableConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    public GlobalKTable<String, String> table(StreamsBuilder kStreamsBuilder) {
        return kStreamsBuilder.globalTable("topic1", Consumed.with(null, null), 
                                            Materialized.as("topic1-store"));
    }
}
```

I'm getting the store like this:

```
streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams().
                store("topic1-store", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
```

this fails with:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR.
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.validateIsRunningOrRebalancing(KafkaStreams.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.store(KafkaStreams.java:1182)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.store(KafkaStreams.java:1169)
```

I can see in that the stream thread is shutting down before this:

```
2020-06-16 13:22:46.943  INFO 72423 --- [    Test worker] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.5.0
        2020-06-16 13:22:46.944  INFO 72423 --- [    Test worker] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84
        2020-06-16 13:22:46.944  INFO 72423 --- [    Test worker] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1592299366943
        2020-06-16 13:22:46.946  INFO 72423 --- [ad | producer-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Cluster ID: aKrIp_7wQcqF9OlSUoBgSQ
        2020-06-16 13:22:47.496  INFO 72423 --- [    Test worker] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [app-d09c3f52-8d77-4814-944b-ba08b79ed8a4] State transition from ERROR to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
        2020-06-16 13:22:47.497  INFO 72423 --- [ms-close-thread] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [app-d09c3f52-8d77-4814-944b-ba08b79ed8a4-StreamThread-1] Informed to shut down
        2020-06-16 13:22:47.497  INFO 72423 --- [ms-close-thread] o.a.k.s.p.internals.GlobalStreamThread   : global-stream-thread [app-d09c3f52-8d77-4814-944b-ba08b79ed8a4-GlobalStreamThread] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
        2020-06-16 13:22:47.557  INFO 72423 --- [balStreamThread] o.a.k.s.p.internals.GlobalStreamThread   : global-stream-thread [app-d09c3f52-8d77-4814-944b-ba08b79ed8a4-GlobalStreamThread] Shutting down
        2020-06-16 13:22:47.571  INFO 72423 --- [balStreamThread] o.a.k.s.p.internals.GlobalStreamThread   : global-stream-thread [app-d09c3f52-8d77-4814-944b-ba08b79ed8a4-GlobalStreamThread] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
        2020-06-16 13:22:47.571  INFO 72423 --- [balStreamThread] o.a.k.s.p.internals.GlobalStreamThread   : global-stream-thread [app-d09c3f52-8d77-4814-944b-ba08b79ed8a4-GlobalStreamThread] Shutdown complete
```

After some experiments I made it work by adding to my configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public KStream kStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamsBuilder) {
        return kStreamsBuilder.stream("some-topic", Consumed.with(null, null));
    }
```

So basically when I have any KStream defined (consuming from any topic) the stream thread stays alive and everything works as before the upgrade.
My question is, what would be the correct way to do it without this useless bean (and topic).

EDIT

There was a similar issue discussed here: [Kafka Streams 2.5.0 requires input topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61342530/kafka-streams-2-5-0-requires-input-topic)
Looks like this will be fixed in kafka-streams 2.5.1 and util then setting `num.stream.threads: 0` is nicer workaround than what declaring dummy stream.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have nothing to do with Spring and is caused by some internal changes in the kafka-streams classes.

This works fine with Boot 2.2.x (Kafka-streams 2.3.x).

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class So62406117Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So62406117Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public GlobalKTable<String, String> table(StreamsBuilder kStreamsBuilder) {
        return kStreamsBuilder.globalTable("topic1", Consumed.with(null, null),
                Materialized.as("topic1-store"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean fb) {
        return args -> {
            ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<Object, Object> store =
                    fb.getKafkaStreams().store("topic1-store", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
            System.out.println(store);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

But fails with Boot 2.3 (Kafka-Streams 2.5.0).

We are definitely starting the `KafkaStreams` (in the factory bean `start()` method, but during that `start()` we get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Consumer is not subscribed to any topics or assigned any partitions
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1228) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:853) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:753) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]

2020-06-16 17:44:02.700  INFO 10635 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [foo-235af8e6-6618-4e73-86ad-75307130004b-StreamThread-1] State transition from STARTING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
2020-06-16 17:44:02.700  INFO 10635 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [foo-235af8e6-6618-4e73-86ad-75307130004b-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
2020-06-16 17:44:02.700  INFO 10635 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=foo-235af8e6-6618-4e73-86ad-75307130004b-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2020-06-16 17:44:02.700  INFO 10635 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=foo-235af8e6-6618-4e73-86ad-75307130004b-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
2020-06-16 17:44:02.704  INFO 10635 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [foo-235af8e6-6618-4e73-86ad-75307130004b-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
2020-06-16 17:44:02.704  INFO 10635 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [foo-235af8e6-6618-4e73-86ad-75307130004b] State transition from REBALANCING to ERROR
2020-06-16 17:44:02.704 ERROR 10635 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [foo-235af8e6-6618-4e73-86ad-75307130004b] All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.
2020-06-16 17:44:02.704  INFO 10635 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [foo-235af8e6-6618-4e73-86ad-75307130004b-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right. 
This is a problem in Kafka 2.5.0 and it will be fixed in 2.5.1. I've edited my original post.