# Kafka Streams: Define multiple Kafka Streams using Spring Cloud Stream for each set of topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying to do a simple POC with Kafka Streams. However I am getting exception while starting the application. I am using Spring-Kafka, Kafka-Streams 2.5.1 with Spring boot 2.3.5
Kafka stream configuration

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaStreamsConfig {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaStreamsConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> processAAA() {
        return input -> input.peek((key, value) -> log
                .info("AAA Cloud Stream Kafka Stream processing : {}", input.toString().length()));
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> processBBB() {
        return input -> input.peek((key, value) -> log
                .info("BBB Cloud Stream Kafka Stream processing : {}", input.toString().length()));
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> processCCC() {
        return input -> input.peek((key, value) -> log
                .info("CCC Cloud Stream Kafka Stream processing : {}", input.toString().length()));
    }

    /*
    @Bean
    public KafkaStreams kafkaStreams(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "groupId-1"););
        props.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerde.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, JsonNode.class);
        final KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(kafkaStreamTopology(), props);
        kafkaStreams.start();
        return kafkaStreams;
    }

    @Bean
    public Topology kafkaStreamTopology() {
        final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        streamsBuilder.stream(Arrays.asList(AAATOPIC, BBBInputTOPIC, CCCInputTOPIC));
        return streamsBuilder.build();
    } */
}
```

**application.yaml** configured is like below. The idea is that I have 3 input and 3 output topics.
The component takes input from input topic and gives output to outputtopic.

```
spring:
  application.name: consumerapp-1
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: processAAA;processBBB;processCCC
    stream:
      kafka.binder: 
          brokers: 127.0.0.1:9092
          autoCreateTopics: true
          auto-add-partitions: true
      kafka.streams.binder:
          configuration: 
            commit.interval.ms: 1000
            default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
            default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
      bindings:
        processAAA-in-0:
          destination: aaaInputTopic
        processAAA-out-0:
          destination: aaaOutputTopic
        processBBB-in-0:
          destination: bbbInputTopic
        processBBB-out-0:
          destination: bbbOutputTopic
        processCCC-in-0:
          destination: cccInputTopic
        processCCC-out-0:
          destination: cccOutputTopic
```

Exception thrown is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to prepareConsumerBinding public abstract void org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream.to(java.lang.String,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced)  but no delegate has been set.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KStreamBoundElementFactory$KStreamWrapperHandler.invoke(KStreamBoundElementFactory.java:134)
```

Can anyone help me with Kafka Streams Spring-Kafka code samples for processing with multiple input and output topics.

**Updates: 21-Jan-2021**

After removing all kafkaStreams and kafkaStreamsTopology beans configuration iam getting below message in an infinite loop. The messages consumption is still not working. I have checked the subscription in application.yaml with the @Bean Function definitions. they all look ok to me but still I get this cross wiring error. **I have replaced the application.properties with application.yaml above**

```
    [consumerapp-1-75eec5e5-2772-4999-acf2-e9ef1e69f100-StreamThread-1] [Consumer clientId=consumerapp-1-75eec5e5-2772-4999-acf2-e9ef1e69f100-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=consumerapp-1] We received an assignment [cccParserTopic-0] that doesn't match our current subscription Subscribe(bbbParserTopic); it is likely that the subscription has changed since we joined the group. Will try re-join the group with current subscription
2021-01-21 14:12:43,336 WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [consumerapp-1-75eec5e5-2772-4999-acf2-e9ef1e69f100-StreamThread-1] [Consumer clientId=consumerapp-1-75eec5e5-2772-4999-acf2-e9ef1e69f100-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=consumerapp-1] We received an assignment [cccParserTopic-0] that doesn't match our current subscription Subscribe(bbbParserTopic); it is likely that the subscription has changed since we joined the group. Will try re-join the group with current subscription
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem. I am writing this for the benefit of others.
If you want to include multiple streams in your single app jar then the key is in defining **multiple application Ids** that is one per each of your streams. I knew this all along but I was not aware on how to define it. Finally the answer is something I have managed to dig out after reading the SCSt documentation. Below is how the application.yaml can be defined.
**application.yaml** is like below

```
spring:
  application.name: kafkaMultiStreamConsumer
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: processAAA; processBBB; processCCC --> // needed for Imperative @StreamListener
    stream:
      kafka: 
        binder:
          brokers: 127.0.0.1:9092
          min-partition-count: 3
          replication-factor: 2
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: transaction-id-2000
          autoCreateTopics: true
          auto-add-partitions: true
        streams:
          binder:
            functions: 
            // needed for functional
              processBBB: 
                application-id: SampleBBBapplication
              processAAA: 
                application-id: SampleAAAapplication
              processCCC: 
                application-id: SampleCCCapplication
            configuration: 
              commit.interval.ms: 1000            
              default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
              default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde        
      bindings:
      // Below is for Imperative Style programming using 
      // the annotation namely @StreamListener, @SendTo in .java class
        inputAAA:
          destination: aaaInputTopic
        outputAAA:
          destination: aaaOutputTopic
        inputBBB:
          destination: bbbInputTopic
        outputBBB:
          destination: bbbOutputTopic
        inputCCC:
          destination: cccInputTopic
        outputCCC:
          destination: cccOutputTopic
     // Functional Style programming using Function<KStream...> use either one of them
     // as both are not required. If you use both its ok but only one of them works
     // from what i have seen @StreamListener is triggered always.
     // Below is from functional style
        processAAA-in-0:
          destination: aaaInputTopic
          group: processAAA-group
        processAAA-out-0:
          destination: aaaOutputTopic
          group: processAAA-group
        processBBB-in-0:
          destination: bbbInputTopic
          group: processBBB-group
        processBBB-out-0:
          destination: bbbOutputTopic
          group: processBBB-group
        processCCC-in-0:
          destination: cccInputTopic
          group: processCCC-group
        processCCC-out-0:
          destination: cccOutputTopic
          group: processCCC-group
```

Once above is defined we now need to define individual java classes where the Stream processing logic is implemented.
Your Java class can be something like below. Create similarly for other 2 or N streams as per your requirement. One example is like below : **AAASampleStreamTask.java**

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(AAASampleChannel.class) // One Channel interface corresponding to in-topic and out-topic
public class AAASampleStreamTask {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AAASampleStreamTask.class);

    @StreamListener(AAASampleChannel.INPUT)
    @SendTo(AAASampleChannel.OUTPUT)
    public KStream<String, String> processAAA(KStream<String, String> input) {
        input.foreach((key, value) -> log.info("Annotation AAA *Sample* Cloud Stream Kafka Stream processing {}", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));
       ...
       // do other business logic
       ...
        return input;
    }
    
    /**
     * Use above or below. Below style is latest startting from ScSt 3.0 if iam not 
     * wrong. 2 different styles of consuming Kafka Streams using SCSt. If we have 
     * both then above gets priority as per my observation
     */     
    /* 
    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> processAAA() {
        return input -> input.peek((key, value) -> log.info(
                "Functional AAA *Sample* Cloud Stream Kafka Stream processing : {}", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));
       ...
     // do other business logic
       ...
    }
    */
}
```

The Channel is required if you want to go with Imperative style programming not for functional.
**AAASampleChannel.java**

```
public interface AAASampleChannel {
    String INPUT = "inputAAA";
    String OUTPUT = "outputAAA";

    @Input(INPUT)
    KStream<String, String> inputAAA();

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    KStream<String, String> outputAAA();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Kafka in the application. When using the binder, you don't need to directly define components required by Spring Kafka such as `KafkaStreams` and `Topology`, rather they are created by `SCSt` implicitly. Can you remove the following beans and try again?

```
@Bean
public KafkaStreams kafkaStreams(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
```

and

```
@Bean
public Topology kafkaStreamTopology() {
```

If you are still facing issues, please share a small sample that can be reproducible, that way we can triage it further.

Comment: Thanks for replying soby. I am trying to get this working. I first tried with functional modeling programming and then with imperative style but both are not working. Strangely. After making the changes you suggested. now iam getting the below exception. I have edited the answer. please check

Comment: what I figured is if I remove the other 2 beans/topics and just keep one Function<KStream...> and 1 topic. Things start working. The moment I add 3 topics & 3 Beans with Function<> it gives me that warning. Can we not have multiple bindings in SCSt. My problem is that I have one set of topics per flow and we have many such topic flows like A-A1-A2, B-B1-B2 and so on where A,A1,B,B1 etc are all topics. For each of these sets I wanted to create a KStream. Is it that per jar we are allowed to have only 1 stream and multiple streams are not allowed. Please let me know