# Can I have/build a "null topology" with Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a Spring Boot Kafka Streams processor. For various reasons, we may have a situation where we need the process to start and run, but there are no topics we wish to subscribe to. In such cases, we just want the process to "sleep", because other liveness/environment checkers depend on it running. Also, it's part of a RedHat OCP cluster, and we don't want the pod to be constantly doing a crash backoff loop. I fully understand that it'll never really do anything until it's restarted with a valid topic(s), but that's OK.

If we start it with no topics, we get this message:`Failed to start bean 'kStreamBuilder'; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table.`

In a test environment, we could just create a topic that's never written to, but in production, we don't have that flexibility, so a programmatic solution would be best. Ideally, I think, if there's a "null topic" abstraction of some sort (a Kafka "/dev/null"), that would look the cleanest in the code.

Best practices, please?

Comment: I found a workaround of sorts here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61342530/kafka-streams-2-5-0-requires-input-topic it works, and I believe, for my uses, is sufficiently "pretty enough" to use. I just used UUID.randomUUID().toString() for the pattern, which is about as unlikely to ever match a topic name as I am to win the lottery :)

Comment: You're welcome to answer your own posts below, rather than use a comment

Comment: You can set the `autoStartup` property on the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `autoStartup` property on the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` to `false` and only `start()` it if you have at least one stream.

If using Spring Boot, it's available as a property:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.streams.auto-startup